# PARSE_DATETIME Function returing space where it shouldnt

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, datetime-format

I am trying to convert `April 2, 2012, 12:00 AM` into a DATETIME/DATE/TIMESTAMP type I dont really mind just not a string.

The problem here however is that within the PARSE_DATETIME function the format string, specifically the %e element string which is for the single digit day is always preceded by a space and in my string I need a comma. The docs read `The day of month as a decimal number (1-31); single digits are preceded by a space.`.

My parse function is as follows `PARSE_DATETIME('%B %e, %Y, %I:%M %p','Timestamp) AS 'Date'` but I get back the error *No matching signature for function PARSE_DATETIME for argument types: STRING, DATETIME. Supported signature: PARSE_DATETIME(STRING, STRING) at [4:5]*

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely seeing the error message because the timestamp field you are using is already a datetime.  Your format string functions as expected with sample data:

```
with sample_data as (
    select 'April 2, 2012, 12:00 AM' as input_string
)

select PARSE_DATETIME('%B %e, %Y, %I:%M %p', input_string) from sample_data
```

Which results in:

[image]

I would make sure your input data is as expected